# ¿Que sucede con los import y export de JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

He estado haciendo una mini aplicacion de piedra, papel o tijera que se divide en dos que se encuentran en dos archivos html (main.html y options.html). Las partes este proyecto son:

> El "login" y el "juego" en sí

el problema es que los elementos de un archivo html no son leídos o reconocidos por el otro archivo html. Ahora lo que intento es conectar cada html con diferentes archivos js pero importar los datos que necesito de un archivo en otro. Mi problema es que quiero exportar unos objetos de un archivo js (main.js) a otro archivo js (box.js) y me dice el siguiente error en el main.js (donde se encuentran los objetos a exportar)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Y este error en el box.js (donde quiero importar los objetos).

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Si alguien sabe como lo que sucede con el export e import o sabe alguna mejor solución a este problema se lo agradeceria un monton.

```html
<!--parte login-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css/style.css">
    <title>Rock Paper or Scissors</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="principalContainer" >
        <h1 class="title">Rock Paper or Scissors Game</h1>
        <div class="players">
            <div class="playerOne" id="playerOne"><p class="text-player">Put Your Name Player One</p>
                <input type="text" name="" id="input" placeholder="Put your name here"><i class="plusButton" id="plusButton"><p class="plus">+</p></i>
            </div>
            <div id="oponente" class="oponent">
                <a href="#oponente"><input type="button" id="computer" value=".VS Computer"></a><a href="#playertwo"><input type="button" id="player" value=" .VS Player"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="playertwo" class="playerTwo">
                <p class="text-player-two">Put Your Name Player Two</p>
                <input type="text" name="" id="input-two" placeholder="Put your name here"><i class="plusButton-two" id="plusButton-two"><p class="plus-two">+</p></i>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="playLink">
            <a href="options.html" class="game">Let´s Play Folks!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../main.js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!--parte juego-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css/gameStyle.css">
    <title>Rock Paper or Scissors</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="scoreboard">
            <p class="points" id="points">0:0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="playerPoints" id="playerPoints">
            PlayerName
        </div>
        <div class="enemyPoints" id="enemyPoints">
            Computer
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="turnText" id="turnText">
                Your turn Player 1</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="options">
            <div class="rockContainer">
                <img src="../img/fist.png" alt="rock" class="rock" id="rock">
            </div>
            <div class="paperContainer">
                <img src="../img/hand.png" alt="paper" class="paper" id="paper">
            </div>
            <div class="scissorsContainer">
                <img src="../img/scissors.png" alt="scissors" class="scissors" id="scissors">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert">
            <p class="winner" id="winner">Paper cover Rock. You won player one!</p>
            <a href="main.html" class="newGame" id="newGame">Lets go to the menu!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="seeStats">
            <a href="#stats" class="statsButton">See Stadistics</a>
        </div>
        <div id="stats" class="modal" onload="stadistics()">
            <a href="#"><img src="../img/x-mark.png" alt="exit" class="exit"></a>
            <div class="stats">
                <img src="../img/refresh.png" alt="refresh" class="refresh" id="refresh">
                <p class="statsTitle">Stadistics</p>
                <ul class="gameList" id="gameList">
                    <!--<li>
                        <p class="player">Player1</p>
                        <p class="finalScore">0:3</p>
                        <p class="secondPlayer">Player2</p>
                    </li>-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../main.js/box.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
"use strict";
//main.js

//selecting DOM elements

//login page
const firstInput= document.getElementById("input");
const firstPlusButton= document.getElementById("plusButton");
const compButton= document.getElementById("computer");
const playerButton= document.getElementById("player");
const secondInput= document.getElementById("input-two");
const secondPlusButton= document.getElementById("plusButton-two");


//game DOM elements
const playerName= document.getElementById("playerPoints");
const points= document.getElementById("points");
const enemyName= document.getElementById("enemyPoints");
const turnText= document.getElementById("turnText");
const rock= document.getElementById("rock");
const paper= document.getElementById("paper");
const scissors= document.getElementById("scissors");
const winnerText= document.getElementById("winner");
const menu= document.getElementById("newGame");


let playerOne= {
    name: loginPlayerOne(),
    turn: true,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

let playerTwo= {
    name: loginPlayerTwo(),
    play: playingPlayer(), 
    turn: false,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

let computer= {
    name: "Computer",
    play:playingComputer(),
    turn: false,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

    
function loginPlayerOne(){
    firstPlusButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        playerOne.name= firstInput.value;
        console.log(playerOne.name);
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
        if(event.keyCode===13){
            playerOne.name= firstInput.value;
            console.log(playerOne.name);
        }
    });
}

function loginPlayerTwo(){
    playerButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{ 
        secondPlusButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            playerTwo.name= secondInput.value;
            console.log(playerTwo.name);
        })

        document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
            if(event.keyCode===13){
                playerTwo.name= secondInput.value;
                console.log(playerTwo.name);
            }
        })

        
       
    })
}


function playingComputer(){
    compButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        console.log("Estas jugando contra la computadora");
        versusComputer();
    })
};

function playingPlayer(){
    playerButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        console.log("Estas jugando contra un jugador");
        versusPlayer();
    })
};


export {playerOne,playerTwo,computer};
```

```js
import {playerOne,playerTwo,computer} from "./main.js";

//box.js

console.log(computer);
console.log(playerOne);
console.log(playerTwo);


//game DOM elements
const playerName= document.getElementById("playerPoints");
const points= document.getElementById("points");
const enemyName= document.getElementById("enemyPoints");
const turnText= document.getElementById("turnText");
const rock= document.getElementById("rock");
const paper= document.getElementById("paper");
const scissors= document.getElementById("scissors");
const winnerText= document.getElementById("winner");
const menu= document.getElementById("newGame");


function versusPlayer(){

    playerName.innerHTML= playerOne.name;    
        
    if(playerOne.turn===true){
        
        rock.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            console.log("rock")
            playerOne.option= "rock";
            playerOne.turn= false;
            console.log(playerOne.option);
            console.log(playerOne.turn);
        });


        paper.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            playerOne.option= "paper";
            playerOne.turn= false;
            console.log(playerOne.option);
            console.log(playerOne.turn);
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mira, estuve investigando y encontré esta página que dice cómo resolverlo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Tienes que colocar en la etiqueta script el atributo `type="module"` en las dos etiquetas y listo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: oye estaba intentando lo que dijiste pero ahora me dice este error: "Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/tecnico/Desktop/Proyectos%20de%20programacion/Piedra,%20Papel%20o%20Tijeras/main.js/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. "

Answer (score 3):

También tuve el mismo problema. Resulta que los módulos de JS sólo funcionan bajo comunicación HTTP, esto quiere decir que solo funcionan cuando se comparten entre un servidor y un cliente bajo ese protocolo, la solución de agregar el atributo `type=module` hace efecto en una estructura cliente-servidor instalada.

Te dejo la referencia si quieres saber más: https://javascript.info/modules-intro#what-is-a-module

Por otro lado, si quieres que tu código funcione de manera local usando módulos, implementa `webpack` (el cual es un bundler de módulos, esto unifica todos tus archivos fuentes de JS a un sólo archivo usualmente llamado `main.js`) en tu directorio.

Aquí está la documentación para instalar y configurar https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/